# How to have global values in a file initialized from another file in C?

Tags: c

I'm used to use classes in C++ and Java, and to initialize class members in some method, eg:

**MyClass.java**

```
class MyClass {

    private int var1, var2, var3;

    public init(int var1, int var2, int var3){

        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
        this.var3 = var3;
    }

    public someMethod(int[] data){

        // compute some stuff using data, var1, var2, var3
        // without passing var1, var2, var3 as parameters of someMethod
    }   
}
```

**other file**

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass();
myClass.init(1,2,3);    
myClass.someMethod(data);
```

In my specific case I have a peak detection method with many parameters (defined in some file peakdetection.c) and this method is called in a processing loop (in some other file main.c). It seems that passing my 10+ parameters every time is not optimal (at least in terms of readability), so, since there is no class in C, I'm looking for the standard way to do that.

**EDIT**

Here's what I did:

**peakdetection.c**

```
static struct {

    int var1;
    int var2;
    int var3;
} config;

int init(int var1, int var2, int var3){

    config.var1 = var1;
    config.var2 = var2;
    config.var3 = var3;

    return 0;
}

int someMethod(int[] data){

    // use config.*
}
```

Comment: "Not optimal" in what sense ? And why can't you just have an `init` function in your C implementation, just like the `init` method in your Java or C++ code ? How would that be any different ?

Comment: @PaulR removing the enclosing class code? the variable would then be global to the file?

Comment: you can pass a `struct` to the function which include all the data

Comment: You can either use file (static) globals if you only ever need one instance, or you can have the equivalent of a constructor/destructor pair which allocate/deallocate a struct containing your "instance variables".

Comment: @sundq these data won't change, they are only set once before the processing loop, so it's not necessary to pass them every time.

Comment: @jul since these data set once and not changed,you can don't pass them as arguments,you can declare them as `static` global variables.

Comment: @sundq how do I initialize them?

Comment: Did you even *read* the above comments ?

Comment: I did read the comments, don't get nervous downvoting and closing the question (to whoever did that), I'm trying to understand how C works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `c` you can use **global** variables by defining them in the global space, and also **private global** by defining them as `static`. This way, they will be only visible in the file. You can also create **accessor**:

`foo.h`

```
#ifndef _FOO_
#define _FOO_

/* Declare accessors */
int get_foo(void);
void set_foo(int value);

#endif
```

`foo.c`

```
#include "foo.h"

/* Declare a private global variable */
static int foo = 0;

int get_foo(void)
{
    return foo;
}

void set_foo(int value)
{
    foo = value;
}
```

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    /* Print foo value */
    printf("foo: %d\n", get_foo());

    /* Set foo to 3 */
    set_foo(3);

    /* Print foo value */
    printf("foo: %d\n", get_foo());

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
./a.out
foo: 0
foo: 3
```

Comment: You can also mix this solution with the one from @m-oehm by creating a `static struct mystruct` instead of an `static int` and add an init function as `void init_foo(int var1, int var2, int var2);` in the `foo` files.

Answer (score 4):

Use a structure and provide functions to initialise them:

```
struct mystruct {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int var3;
};

void mystruct_init(struct mystruct *s, int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    s->var1 = var1;
    s->var2 = var2;
    s->var3 = var3;
}

int mystruct_do_stuff(struct mystruct *s, int x)
{
    // do stuff with s->var1, s->var2, etc.
}
```

and use it like this:

```
struct mystruct s;
int y;

mystruct_init(&s, 1, 2, 55);
y = mystruct_do_stuff(&s, 12);
```

This method requires that the definition of the struct is visible to the calling function, i.e. the struct must be defined in a header. If you want to hide the struct's contents from the caller, you should privide functions to create and destroy your structs and that work with pointers to the struct, whose content is opaque to the caller:

```
struct mystruct *mystruct_new(int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    struct mystruct *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));

    s->var1 = var1;
    s->var2 = var2;
    s->var3 = var3;

    return s;
}

void mystruct_destroy(struct mystruct *s)
{
    // other cleanup code
    free(s);
}
```

And use ist like this:

```
struct mystruct *s = mystruct_new(1, 2, 55);

y = mystruct_do_stuff(s, 12);
// do more stuff
mystruct_destroy(s);
```

If your structure is just a collection of simple data, you can omit the constructor and destructor functions and initialise the data directly by position in the struct definition:

```
struct mystruct s = {1, 2, 55};
```

or, if you have more members with desgnated initialisers (C99):

```
struct mystruct s = {.var1 = 1, .var3 = 55, var2 = 2};
```

This requires that the structure of the struct is visible, of course.

This emulates classes (without inheritance or polymorphism), where the pointer to the struct (`this`) is passed explicitly to the function.

Comment: Why do I have to pass the struct in `init` and `mystruct_do_stuff`? Can't I just pass var1, var2 and var3 to `init` and set it to the local (to the file) struct, so that `mystruct_do_stuff` can use it (like in my Java example? I might be too conditioned by OO programming though...

Comment: You pass a pointer to your struct, through which you can access the struct's member variables. In OO languages, you do this by calling the method of the struct, compare `s->do_stuff(x)` with `mystruct_do_stuff(s, x)`. If you just need a single instance and a place to wrap your process parameters tidily together, you might as well use a global struct, which you wouldn't have to pass as argument.

Comment: As `global struct` you mean a static struct, like the `foo` int in jml's answer?

Comment: Yes. If you just use one instance, do that and initialise it either with the `{...}` as I've shown above or by assigning values to the members. (`global` isn't a C keyword. You can make the struct `static`, which means it will be local to the compiled object file. You could access it from other obect files through accessor functions like the `int` in jml's code, though.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was not clear about the scope of the variables. I selected jml's answer and upvoted yours.